# Create dynamic value for script call's key / value pairs

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out how to insert variables into a script that is being loaded to pull a widget into a page. The script looks like this and is run when the page is first accessed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://externalsite.com/embed-widget.js" async>
    { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
</script>
```

What I would like to do is be able to change the values for the keys based on user selection.

```
<a href="#" data-key="value3">Value 3</a>
$('a').on('click',function()({
    var newValue = $(this).attr('data-key');
});
```

Then insert the new value into the key/value pair in the script call and reload the script by changing the code on the page to:
    
        { "key1": "+newValue+", "key2": "value2" }

However - nothing seems to work with this route and the value isn't getting passed. Can this be done with the 'async' tag?

Comment: The script should define a function that takes parameters, and then you call the function with the variables you want.

Comment: `.val()` is for getting the value of an input element. `.attr()` returns the string, you don't need to call `.val()` after it.

Comment: So build the key / value pairs in a function that takes variables and then just call the function in between the script tags?

Comment: You load the external script once, it defines a function. Then you call the function from a different `<script>` tag when you're processing the user input.

Comment: Look at how other widget libraries do it, like jQuery UI. You load the widget library once, then you call functions like `.autocomplete()` and `.datepicker()` with parameters that specify what you want.